# LaraAdmin how to use bigint field type

Tags: laravel, laraadmin

I'm building some application based on LaraAdmin crud generator. I need a field to be a BigInt since the possible values are bigger than a normal Integer. How should I achieve that in order to not make the system crash?

Comment: Just change it over, it won't cause a crash.

Comment: But the "Models" that LaraAdmin works with has a dropdown with defined visualization types that also define the table/column structure, How will it react to a type it does not recognize?

Comment: It'll still be classed as an integer it just means large values can be stored within the database.

Comment: That made the trick, thanks!

Comment: I have added it as an answer for you so that others can can utilise this in the event they ever run into the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is stored already as an integer, simply change the database type to biginteger and it'll be fine as they both store numerical values.